# ngx-bootstrap modal (ng6/bs4) with used with angular2-draggable, doesn't drag the entire modal just what's inside

Tags: bootstrap-4, angular6, ngx-bootstrap

So, I have an app that's done in ng6 and bs4.x

I've installed angular2/draggable from here: [Angular Draggable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-draggable)

And I've used the example for modal here: [ngx-bootstrap/modal](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals)

If you scroll down to: Component#, you'll see the example which I've put below.

THE TEMPLATE:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openModalWithComponent()">Create modal with component</button>
```

THE COMPONENT:

import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { BsModalService, BsModalRef } from 'ngx-bootstrap/modal';

```
@Component({
  selector: 'demo-modal-service-component',
  templateUrl: './service-component.html'
})
export class DemoModalServiceFromComponent {
  bsModalRef: BsModalRef;
  constructor(private modalService: BsModalService) {}

  openModalWithComponent() {
    const initialState = {
      list: [
        'Open a modal with component',
        'Pass your data',
        'Do something else',
        '...'
      ],
      title: 'Modal with component'
    };
    this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalContentComponent, {initialState});
    this.bsModalRef.content.closeBtnName = 'Close';
  }
}

/* This is a component which we pass in modal*/

@Component({
  selector: 'modal-content',
  template: `
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h4 class="modal-title pull-left">{{title}}</h4>
      <button type="button" class="close pull-right" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <ul *ngIf="list.length">
        <li *ngFor="let item of list">{{item}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">{{closeBtnName}}</button>
    </div>
  `
})

export class ModalContentComponent implements OnInit {
  title: string;
  closeBtnName: string;
  list: any[] = [];

  constructor(public bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.list.push('PROFIT!!!');
  }
}
```

The DRAGGABLE feature DOES WORK but in my example, this is what happens:

Finally, here's my @component({...})

Which I used to replace the basic modal in the code for ngx-bootstrap as shown above...

[image: The Modal as it appears when opened]

[image: The Modal when I try to DRAG the container but the modal-content moves OUTSIDE of the container]

[image: Here's the way the modal looks inside the Elements Tab of Google]

Please advise...

Comment: me also facing same issue,

Answer (score 1):

i solve this problem with css:

```
.modal-dialog {
  .modal-content {
    background-color: transparent;
    border: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  .ngDraggable {
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    border-radius: 6px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
}
```

Comment: WOW! Ahmad, thanks but this was over a year ago and I've solved it but I can seriously use your help with this one.... using angular2Draggable - Boundary https://xieziyu.github.io/angular2-draggable/#/draggable/usage/boundary My particular code is the same but it drags "outside" the boundaries of the browser. What I've got it a bit more complicated but it's a modal. I can drag the modal "beyond" the browser's boundaries. It doesn't work like the example. Do you want me to write a new question and then watch for it?  I'll vote up on this for you ok?